# TextBox lost data after postback (listview)

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Good day! In listview I have a text field. The user enters the data and clicks (linkbutton) After postback field loses data or displays the default data (if any). When the textbox is not in the listview, no such problems. ViewState is enabled for the  page.
part of code

```
<asp:ListView ID="mylist" runat="server" DataSourceID="listsource" OnItemDataBound="mylist_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="mylist_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style=" display:inline-block;">
            <div style="float:left;">
                <img src="<%=ResolveUrl("files") %>/<%#Eval("img") %>" alt='<%#Eval("img") %>' class="primage" />
                 <div class="div1" style="width:240px;"> <%#Eval("sample") %></div></div>
                 <div class="card">
                 <asp:TextBox ID="countbox" runat="server" CssClass=""></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="add" runat="server" CssClass="add" CommandName="add">some text</asp:LinkButton>
             </div> 
         </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server side, you should ask if the page is posted back

```
If(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    MyListView.DataBind();
}
```

If you don't, any value posted will be overwritten with the original or default values.

Answer (score 1):

With postback, your data seems to be regenerating with databinding. You can avoid data loss with binding values under an if block that checks the page is not a postback

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //bind my lovely data
}
else
{
    // do nothing
    // dont bind new data with postback because I just pressed a button
}
```

Another solution might be to use AJAX or asynchronous postback with UpdatePanel

Answer (score -1):

Make use of Ajax UpdatePanels  for partial postbacks.
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: That wouldn't solve the problem, and would just complicate things.